# How to create address in sawtooth-seth through REST API

Tags: rest, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am learning [sawtooth-seth](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/seth/releases/latest/introduction.html). I can create key-pair and account using 
**seth-cli-go**. In order to connect with application I need to connect it with REST API. So I used the following REST API.

```
curl --data '{"method":"personal_newAccount","params":["test@123"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:3030
```

But I got the following error msg,

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32069,"message":"Error generating key"},"id":1}
```

seth-rpc server error
 `[00:14:21.966] (7fc28042d700) ERROR  Error generating key: No such file or directory (os error 2)
[00:14:21.966] (7fc28042d700) ERROR  Error generating key`

How to fix this? And where my key-pair will be stored?

Answer (score 0):

> How to fix this?

The code which producing that error message can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth/blob/b7b59adf52815b520e1cb43ba52b702c185f9c7f/rpc/src/calls/personal.rs). 
According to the code, this error came because it has mismatch key with the system. I think you could try [curl with your keypair](https://serverfault.com/questions/913458/how-to-use-rootcert-pem-certificate-with-curl) as well.

> And where my key-pair will be stored?

I read the code to find where it stores the key. You can check the implementation of function `get_key_dir()` in [accounts.rs](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth/blob/b7b59adf52815b520e1cb43ba52b702c185f9c7f/rpc/src/accounts.rs), which states `Some([home.to_str()?, ".sawtooth", "keys"].iter().collect())`

So, your key-pair should be in your [home directory](https://docs.rs/dirs/2.0.2/dirs/fn.home_dir.html).